# Nodejs Socket.io making multiple connection with single client

Tags: node.js, express, sockets, socket.io

socket.js

```
io.on('connection', async socket => {
    console.log('connection', socket.id)
    //Get the chatID of the user and join in a room of the same chatID
    chatID = socket.id;

    //Leave the room if the user closes the socket
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('9****')
        socket.leave(chatID)
    });

    socket.on('connect_error', err => console.log(err));
    socket.on('connect_failed', err => console.log(err));
    socket.on('error', err => console.log(err));

    socket.on('delete_user', async user => {
        let userRecord = await userHandler.getUserById(user.id);
        io.emit(
            'delete_users',
            userRecord
        );
    });

    socket.on('payment', async message => {
        console.log('pay', message)
        let messageRecord = await messageHandler.messageDetail(message.id);
        await messageHandler.updatePayment(message.id, message, messageRecord);
        let updatedMessage = await messageHandler.messageDetail(message.id);
        // callback(updatedMessage);
        io.emit(
            'payment_messages',
            updatedMessage
        );
    });
  
   })
```

I am using socket for the first time and connection event is creating multiple connections for single user like first time it create only 1 connection but if some event is hit again it creates new connection with same client so event is hitting n number of times. I am new to socket and stucked here. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: What does the front end code look like? Usually this is because your connection string on the client is being called each time so it connects multiple times VS just once

Comment: Problaby, the problem is in client-side. Could you show source code where there is the connection call?